# ajax filtering database by multiple select

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, oracle

I'm trying to filter my database using 2 select option
what I want is when the user load the page they can see database result organized in a table, when they choose the the select (drop down list) the table is filtered, they can choose one of the select (drop down list) or both for optimum result. so how can I adjust my code to work as I want it to ? 
I'm using oracle hr database

HTML(home):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showInfo(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("information").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("information").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET","emp.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>


<select name="dep" onchange="showInfo(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a Department:</option>
  <option value="90">Advertisement</option>
  <option value="60">IT</option>
  <option value="100">Finance</option>
  <option value="30">Public relations</option>
  </select>
<select name="manager" onchange="showInfo2(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a Manager:</option>
  <option value="100">Bob</option>
  <option value="103">Lee</option>
  <option value="108">Rose</option>
  <option value="102">Lana</option>
  </select>
<br>
<div id="information"><b>Emp info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

php(emp.php):

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

    $conn = oci_connect('hr', 'hr123', 'Glory-PC:1521/XE');
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID= '".$q."' ");
                oci_execute($stid);


echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>EMAIL</th>
<th>PHONE NUMBER</th>
<th>HIRE DATE</th>
</tr>";
while($row=oci_fetch_array( $stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS )) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FIRST_NAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LAST_NAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['EMAIL'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PHONE_NUMBER'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['HIRE_DATE'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see criteria for what you want to do, but no question. Is what you currently doing not working?

Comment: `emp.php` is basically a function that returns a piece of HTML, so you dont need the `<html>
<body>` and `</body>
</html>` In fact they are probably getting the page confused when you add the `responseText` to the div on the page

Comment: @sean I'm sorry I forgot to mention , how can I adjust my code to work as I want it to do

Comment: So you want a way to search by `dep`, `manager`, or `dep & manager`? What does your code look like to search just by `manager`? Is the `manager` a column in your `employees` table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I removed the tags thank you for your comment, but how can I adjust the code to give me the required result?

Comment: @sean yes I want my code to be able to filter the results using either DEPARTMENT_ID or MANAGER_ID or both and DEPARTMENT_ID , MANAGER_ID are colums in employees table

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I wasn't looking for a free code , I was looking for guidance to accomplish the required results, what I don't know is how to send the value of the second a select and use it in my query